# How to create a (lua) function to run a particular command in the shell on the currently open file, within neovim

Tags: neovim, command-line, formatting, lua

If I'm working on a file I might want to run a particular command which uses the file within the shell.

Example - running black (python formatter) on an open file.

Ideally I'd like to be able to enter something like `<leader>b` and have that run:

`:silent! !poetry run black %` (run black on the current buffer)

I currently have:

```
vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>b", ":silent! !poetry run black %<CR>")
```

Which does work - but I feel as though the use of the string `:silent! !poetry run black %<CR>` *might* be an old approach?

I would also like this to only work for python files - at the moment If I open a `.sql` file it will try to run the same command, though I might want to use something else for that file type.